# getting max value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, client, max

simple question. I'm new to using arrays and multiple classes and could use some help. Basically, my program is supposed to sort the array in ascending order(done) and then output the max number. But I have to use two classes (client class and other) I always seem to have trouble bringing the code from one class and implementing it into another. I'm trying to implement my getMaxValue into the client class to output it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple or overlooking it. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

First Class:

```
public class Chapter8Number16{

public static void selectionSort(int[]array){   

    int temp;
    int max;
    int numbers[] = new int[0];

    for(int i = 0; i< array.length;i++){

        max=indexOfLargestElement(array, array.length-i);

        temp=array[max];

        array[max]=array[array.length-i-1];

        array[array.length-i-1]=temp;           

    }
}
    private static int indexOfLargestElement(int[]array,int size){

        int index=0;
        for(int i = 1; i<size;i++){
            if (array[i]>array[index])
                index=i;
        }
return index;   
}
    public static int getMaxValue(int[] array){  
          int maxValue = array[0];  
          for(int i=1;i < array.length;i++){  
          if(array[i] > maxValue){  
          maxValue = array[i];  

             }  
         }  
                 return maxValue;  

 }
}
```

Client Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Chapter8Number16Client {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[]numbers=new int[6];
        int highest=0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            numbers[i]=rand.nextInt(100)+1;
            highest += numbers[i];
        }


        Chapter8Number16.selectionSort(numbers);
        Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(array);

        System.out.println("The sorted array: ");
        for(int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++)
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + "\t");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("The highest number is: ");
        System.out.println(maxValue[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is maxValue[] declared?

Comment: Please format your code using an IDE. This will help you and us read the code.

Comment: @zerocool In the first class towards bottom

Comment: Does your code even compiled?Do it this way


`System.out.println("max value :"+Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(numbers));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has compilation issues, anyways, below code should help:

```
System.out.println("The highest number is: "+Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(numbers));
```

Comment: Will do as soon as time allows.

Comment: Dude, i meant accept the above solution as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value is returned by your function,so you must assign it to a variable

```
int max = Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(numbers);
System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: there is no array declared with the name array in OP main class

Answer (score 0):

You must save the maxvalue into a variable like

```
int max = Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(array);
```

ora if you want just to print it:

```
System.out.println(Chapter8Number16.getMaxValue(array));
```